# Change part of href value based on a parent div attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html

```html
<div class="1" style="" title="NeedthisText TextIDontneed">
<div class="2">
<div class="3">
<a target="_blank" href="/NeedToChange/DispForm.aspx?ID=1">Link</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to know how can I change "/NeedToChange/" part of the href depending if the title value of the div with `class="1"` contains some text I need.

Any Help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm really sorry i didnt mean it like that

Comment: No problem, thankfully your edit was minor. Sometimes users make a tiny edit that crucially changes the answers outcome... All good :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes cannot start with Number! (JS might work but CSS will fail and your document will not validate.)

if `"NeedToChange"` is something you cannot control you can Regex target and replace any text between slash characters `/unknownFolder/`, `/anything/`

```js
$(".1[title]").each(function(){

  var title = this.title.split(" ")[0]; // Get only 1st part of title

  $(this).find(".3 a").attr("href", function(idx, val){
    return  val.replace(/^\/([^\/]+)/, "/"+title);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="1" style="" title="SomeText1 I_DONT NEED this">
  <div class="2">
    <div class="3">
      <a target="_blank" href="/NeedToChange/DispForm.aspx?ID=1">Link ID=1</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="1" style="" title="WOOOOOW NeitherThis">
  <div class="2">
    <div class="3">
      <a target="_blank" href="/NeedToChange/DispForm.aspx?ID=37">Link ID=37</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the above will result in the new hrefs:

```
/SomeText1/DispForm.aspx?ID=1
/WOOOOOW/DispForm.aspx?ID=1
```

---

- `[title]` in `$(".1[title]")` makes sure that we're targeting `.1` (BTW not a valid classs name :) ) element that actually HAS a title.
- Than you `.find()` it's inner `.3` Anchor child and access it's `.attr("href",` property `return`ing a `replace` using RegExp:
  [`/^\/([^\/]+)/` Explained on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/fF3jO5/1)

Answer (score 0):

You would do it in a way like this:

```
if ($('.one').attr('title') == 'SomeText1') {
    $('a[href*="/NeedToChange/"]').each(function(){
        var newLink = $(this).attr('href').replace('/NeedToChange/','/NewLink/');
        $(this).attr('href',newLink);
    });
}
```

I changed the class to 'one' since you shouldn't start a class with a number.

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/cewmy4wb/).

Answer (score 0):

Looping through all of the links and getting the parents title as follow:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s48ckgxd/1/)

```
$( ".3 a" ).each(function(){
    var $parent = $( this ).closest( ".1" ),
        title = $parent.attr( "title" ),
        link = "/" + title + "/DispForm.aspx?ID=1";
    $( this ).attr( "href", link );
});
```

This seems to work fine for the following html:

```
<div class="1" style="" title="SomeText1">
    <div class="2">
        <div class="3">
            <a target="_blank" href="/NeedToChange/DispForm.aspx?ID=1">Link 1</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="1" style="" title="SomeText2">
    <div class="2">
        <div class="3">
            <a target="_blank" href="/NeedToChange/DispForm.aspx?ID=1">Link 2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

sorry saw the title with a space just now. Will look for update.

update 1:

like Roko C. Buljan mentioned you should probably split the title in an array and get the first element of it.

```
$('.1').each(function (){
    var title = $(this).attr("title"),
        clTitle = title.split(" ")[0];

    var $link = $(this).find(".3 a"),
        href = $link.attr("href"),
        newHref = href.replace("NeedToChange", clTitle);

   if(typeof $(this).attr('title') !== 'undefined') {
        $link.attr("href", newHref);
   }

});
```

updated fiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s48ckgxd/2/)

Comment: I'd rather make sure the `title` exists at all, cause your code would destroy a valid link... but that's probably just being too picky...

Comment: Also you're hardcoding `"/DispForm.aspx?ID=1"` into JS presuming that it will not be changed from within HTML (is immutable)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and interest you certnainly point me in the right direction i gonna try to use something like  indexOf title intead of the split